# ErrorDocument 404 print file name

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a file `index.php`, and in the same level a `.htaccess` with this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

When i generate a not found error is printed a page with the name of the file, so, in this case i only see `index.php` as literal text. What i want is obviously a redirect to the homepage.

Any idea about this problem?

```
www\site 
  -index.php
  -.htaccess
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

In the [ErrorDocument docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser. Examples:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://foo.example.com/cgi-bin/tester
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription_info.html
ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry can't allow you access today"
```

So if it's not a FQDN or something that starts with a `/`, it is assumed that you  want a customized message to be displayed.

Comment: if `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` doesn work for you it means index.php is NOT in your directory root - directory root is usually the place you see just after you logged in into your FTP :) very common is `ErrorDocument 404 /www/index.php` or `ErrorDocument 404 /domain/www/index.php` or just `ErrorDocument 404 /domain/index.php` - this may not be clear for everyone :)

Comment: And if I combine your dir structure and my comment I get: `ErrorDocument 404 /www/site/index.php`  Hope I helped. :)